# Querying across multiple fields with different boosts in Solr

Tags: solr, solrnet

In Solr, what is the best way of querying across different fields where each query on each field has a different weighting?

We're using C# and ASP.NET, with [SolrNet](https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) being used to query Solr.  Our index looks a bit like this:

- document_id
- title
- text_content
- tags
- [some more fields...]

This is then queried using keywords, where each keyword has a different weight.  So, for example, "ipad" might have a weight of 40, but "android" might have a weight of 25.

In conjunction with this, each field has a different base weight.  For example, keywords are more valuable than page title, which are more valuable than text content.

So, we end up with something like the following:

- title^25
- text_content^10
- tags^50

And the following keywords:

- ipad^25
- apple^22
- microsoft^15
- windows^15
- software^20
- computer^18

So, each search query has a different weighting, and each field has a different weight.  As a result, we end up with search criteria that looks like this:

- title:ipad^50
- title:apple^47
- title:microsoft^40
- [more titles...]
- text_content:ipad^35
- text_content:apple^32
- text_content:microsoft^25
- [lots more...]

This translates into a very, very long search query, which exceeds the limit allowed.  It also seems like a very inefficient way of doing things, and I was wondering if there's a better way of achieving this.

Effectively, we have a list of keywords with varied weights, and a list of fields in Solr which also have varied weights, and the idea is to query the index to retrieve the most relevant documents.

Further complicating this matter, though it may be out of the scope of this question, is that the query also includes filters to filter out documents.  This is done using the following type of query:

```
&fq=(-document_id:4f845eb321c90b0aec5ee0eb)&fq=(-document_id:4f845cd421c90b0aec5ee041)&fq=(-document_id:4f845cea21c90b0aec5ee049)&fq=(-document_id:4f845cf821c90b0aec5ee04d)&fq=(-document_id:4f845d0e21c90b0aec5ee056)&fq=(-document_id:4f845d3521c90b0aec5ee064)&fq=(-document_id:4f845d3921c90b0aec5ee065)&fq=(-document_id:4f845d4921c90b0aec5ee06b)&fq=(-document_id:4f845d7521c90b0aec5ee07b)&fq=(-document_id:4f845d9021c90b0aec5ee084)&fq=(-document_id:4f845dac21c90b0aec5ee08e)&fq=(-document_id:4f845dbc21c90b0aec5ee093)
```

These can also add a lot of characters to the search query, and it would be good if there was also a better way to handle this as well.

Any help or advice is most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to add those default parameters to your requesthandler configuration within `solrconfig.xml`. They are always the same, right?

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="qf">title^25 text_content^10 tags^50</str>
    </lst>  
</requestHandler>
```

You should be able to add your static filters and so on, so that you don't have to specify those values unless you want to do something different from the default, ending up with urls a lot shorter.

Comment: Thought about this, though the boosts also change depending on the search terms, so I'm not sure how valuable a default boost value is.  For example, title may have a *base* boost of 25, but then the boost for each term being searched will be added to this, to create something like this - title:foo^35 title:bar^40 title:foobar^30.